# How to make checkbox show/hide SVG-Content

Tags: javascript, css, svg

i have rectangles and lines in SVG together with a checkbox. I want somehow to make a checked checkbox to show the content and when its checked, otherwise not. So for example: When the checkbox for "areas" are checked the "area rectangles" will be shown and the same for the "river-lines".

It does not seem very hard but I'm totally new to JavaScript and cant find a way to make it work.

The script is to be in HTML and be able to be shown on a web browser. Everything is visible but i cant get the check boxes to work.

I have tried to build functions with "onClick" and to change the color to "none".

```html
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Web Mapping using SVG</title>
  <script>
  </script>
  <style>
 </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <form>
   <fieldset style="width:600px; height:600px">
    <legend>Layers</legend>


    <input type="checkbox" id="areaCbx" /><strong                                                    id="areaTXT">Area</strong><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="riverCbx"  /><strong id="riverTXT">River</strong><br>
    <hr />
    
    
    <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    
 <g id="AreaSVG" >
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="200"   />
      <rect x="120" y="0" width="100" height="200"   />
      <rect x="280" y="0" width="100" height="200"  />
      <rect x="400" y="0" width="100" height="200"   />
      <rect x="0" y="260" width="100" height="200"  />
      <rect x="120" y="260" width="100" height="200"  />
      <rect x="240" y="260" width="100" height="200"  />
      <rect x="360" y="260" width="100" height="200"  />
    </g>
    <g id="RiverSVG">
      
                    <line x1="0" y1="230" x2="500" y2="230"   style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:6"/>
                    <line x1="250" y1="230" x2="250" y2="0" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:6"/>
                    <line x1="0" y1="500" x2="500" y2="500" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:6"/>
      
   </g>
      </svg>
   </fieldset>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the question is not very clear and the code is not readily runnable. Can you explain more on the functionality and maybe paste a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) link

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have posted the full code that should be able to read as a HTML through a web browser. What i want is to have the check boxes determine if the rectangles (AreaSVG) or lines (RiverSVG) are shown. if the checkbox with the id id="areaCbx" is checked it should show the are rectangles, otherwise not.

Comment: Typo here `<<g id="AreaSVG" >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So seems you just want to show/hide parts of SVG depending on which checkbox checked?
if so:

```
<style>
svg #AreaSVG ,
svg #RiverSVG {
display: none;
}
#areaCbx:checked ~ svg #AreaSVG { display: block; }
#riverCbx:checked ~ svg #RiverSVG { display: block; }
<style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with CSS (also you had 2 typos `<<g` and `"y2="0"`)

```css
svg > g {
  display: none;
}
#riverCbx:checked ~ svg #RiverSVG {
  display: block;
}
#areaCbx:checked ~ svg #AreaSVG {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
        <fieldset style="width:600px; height:600px">
            <legend>Layers</legend>


<input type="checkbox" id="areaCbx" /><strong                                                    id="areaTXT">Area</strong><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="riverCbx"  /><strong id="riverTXT">River</strong><br>
            <hr />


<svg width="100%" height="100%">

<g id="AreaSVG" >
                    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="200"   />
                    <rect x="120" y="0" width="100" height="200"   />
                    <rect x="280" y="0" width="100" height="200"  />
                    <rect x="400" y="0" width="100" height="200"   />
                    <rect x="0" y="260" width="100" height="200"  />
                    <rect x="120" y="260" width="100" height="200"  />
                    <rect x="240" y="260" width="100" height="200"  />
                    <rect x="360" y="260" width="100" height="200"  />
</g>
<g id="RiverSVG">

                <line x1="0" y1="230" x2="500" y2="230"   style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:6"/>
                <line x1="250" y1="230" x2="250" y2="0" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:6"/>
                <line x1="0" y1="500" x2="500" y2="500" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:6"/>

        </g>
  </svg>
        </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the (:checked) psuedo selector, with the "non immidiate relative selector" (~)

```
#riverCbx:checked ~ svg {
 display: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A javascript solution would probably be more reliable if you can't assume that the DOM structure (CSS selectors would be dependent on) would never change.

```js
areaTXT.addEventListener('click', function(){
  so_SVG.classList.toggle('svg--hidden');
});
```

```css
.svg--hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset style="width:600px; height:600px">
    <legend>Layers</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" id="areaCbx" /><strong id="areaTXT">Area</strong><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="riverCbx" /><strong id="riverTXT">River</strong><br>
    <hr />
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" id="so_SVG">
      <g id="AreaSVG" >
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="200"/>
          <rect x="120" y="0" width="100" height="200"/>
          <rect x="280" y="0" width="100" height="200"/>
          <rect x="400" y="0" width="100" height="200"/>
          <rect x="0" y="260" width="100" height="200"/>
          <rect x="120" y="260" width="100" height="200"/>
          <rect x="240" y="260" width="100" height="200"/>
          <rect x="360" y="260" width="100" height="200"/>
      </g>
      <g id="RiverSVG">
        <line x1="0" y1="230" x2="500" y2="230" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:6"/>
        <line x1="250" y1="230" x2="250" y2="0" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:6"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="500" x2="500" y2="500" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:6"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Note:** I'm using `id`s of elements here as they will already be defined in the global scope as variables.